# Zipping increment file names using Zip Utils

Tags: c++, dynamic, zip, filenames

Hello I've been using "Zip Utils" from
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7530/Zip-Utils-clean-elegant-simple-C-Win32

to zip files and folders. the easy thing is if the file name is known i just need to do something like this

```
HZIP hz; DWORD writ;
hz = CreateZip(_T("filename\\image1.zip"),0);
```

The problem is I get errors when trying to zip files by incrementing file names within a loop

```
    int i= 0;
for(i=0; i<record; i++)
{
     ZipAdd(hz,_T("doc"+i+1+".kml"), _T("filename\\doc"+i+1+".kml"));
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an issue with how to use Zip Utils.  You are attempting to concatenate strings the way it is done in some other language, but that is not C++.  You need to format a string argument with your incremented file name first before passing that string into ZipAdd.

Comment: @GX Error 6 error C2665: 'ZipAdd' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types

with
`int i= 0;
 string filepath1 = "doc"+i+1+".kml";
 string filepath2 = "GenFiles\\doc"+i+1+".kml";
 for(i=0; i<record; i++)
 {
  ZipAdd(hz,_T(filepath1), _T(filepath2));
 }`
Error 8 error C2065: 'Lfilepath1' : undeclared identifier
Error 8 error C2065: 'Lfilepath2' : undeclared identifier
Error 7 error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'System::String ^' to 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'

Comment: System::String^ looks like C# or .NET/CLR, not native C++.  You need some help with how to create a string with an incrementing number inserted int it at run-time.

Comment: yep, would you be able to help me with that?

Comment: If the answer below solves your problem, mark it as "Accepted."  Also it would be helpful if you edited the title and tags of the question to show that it about string concatenation, not Zip Utils or filenames.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the most efficient way to write the code but it illustrates the concept.  Use to_string( ... ) to convert a number to a string for concatenation.  It requires a long long argument, not an int.

```
long long i;
string filepath1, filepath2;
for(i=0; i<record; i++)
{
   filepath1 = "doc" + to_string(i + 1) + ".klm";
   filepath2 = "GenFiles\\doc" + to_string(i + 1) + ".klm";
   ZipAdd(hz,filepath1,filepath2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but i know have to do that part. there is only on problem for 
`ZipAdd(hz,_T(filepath1), _T(filepath2));`

I get two errors 
`error C2065: 'Lfilepath1' : undeclared identifier`
`error C2065: 'Lfilepath2' : undeclared identifier`

Comment: I copied your other mistake from your code into my answer.  The _T( ) around the filepath arguments is not needed.  You may need something like filepath1.c_str depending on the requirements of ZipAdd.

Comment: Almost there when trying `ZipAdd(hz,filepath1.c_str(), filepath2.c_str());` i get 'ZipAdd' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types error if it helps this is from the zip.h `ZRESULT ZipAdd(HZIP hz,const TCHAR *dstzn, const TCHAR *fn);
ZRESULT ZipAdd(HZIP hz,const TCHAR *dstzn, void *src,unsigned int len);`

Comment: We have left the realm of a Stack Overflow Question+Answer and turned this into a tutoring chat.  You need some work with the documentation of your particular language and development environment regarding strings.  TCHAR and T( ) are macros that redefine the size and format of a char depending on compiler options. Other elements such as string and System::String may also mean something different depending on what compiler options are set.  You need to be sure that all your different uses of strings are compatible or you need to convert between the types.

Comment: Thanks ill try to work it out =) if now ill need to start a new question right. hmm is there a way to vote or select best answers? thanks